# Regular Expression to get a number between two strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

Here are samples:

- example 1:
  `string1<span id="header">5655811</span>string2`
- example 2:
  `string3<span id="header">51481</span>string4`
- example 3:
  `string5<span id="header">854211</span>string6`

How can I get the number between `<span id="header">` and `</span>` with JavaScript regex?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Comment: Aside: Ids should be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: You can't assume from his answer that he's not using IDs uniquely: he's just presenting three examples, they could be on different pages, or different loads of the same page, and the `header` ID could still be unique.  Not that it's ever a bad thing to remind people that IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how safe you want to be.  If you're sure that all of your input looks exactly like you have in your message, you can use:

```
var n = Number( input.match( /<span id="header">(\d+)<\/span>/ )[1] );
```

A slightly safer version would be:

```
var n;
var match = input.match( /<span id="header">\s*(\d+)\s*<\/span>/ );
if( match ) {
    n = Number( match[1] );
} else {
    // do error handling here
}
```